# Android - Wait for variable to be initialized in ViewModel to proceed in Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm using kotlin coroutines to fetch data from my Room database, and I need to wait for the variables to be initialized in my ViewModel to use them in my Fragment, mainly to initialize other things like a GoogleMap but also for other purposes (like check condition for navigation, etc...). 
Plus, I actually need to wait for an Args from Navigation so the first call is from Fragment to ViewModel, and only then the coroutines are fired

I've seen multiple ways of doing that, but I'm pretty new to Android and none match the way I'm already using, and most of the time it's was way too complicated and I didn't understand.

Actually i'm using this in the Fragment :

```
Handler().postDelayed(
{My code...}, 50)
```

But I know it's not a clean way to do it at all, and sometimes the variables are not even initialized after 50ms. I've also tried with a simple

```
While (var == null){}
My code...
```

But it's also very barbarian and just make the app freeze.

Here is an example of my Fragment

```
var currentSession: Session? = null

val args = SessionDetailsFragmentArgs.fromBundle(arguments!!)
viewModel.initializeSession(args.sessionID)

viewModel.session.observe(this, Observer{
    currentSession = it
})
//I need to wait for currentSession to continue
..Doing stuff with currentSession..
```

And here is my ViewModel :

```
private var _session = MutableLiveData<Session?>()
val session: LiveData<Session?>
    get() = _session

fun initializeSession(key: Long) {
    uiScope.launch {
        _session.value = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val session = dataSessionSource.getSession(key)
            session
        }
    }

}
```

I've shorten it a bit but it's more to have an idea of how i'm proceeding. Everything compile and work as needed

What I need is like a function `MyVariable.OnInitialized() { ... }` That launch the code only when `MyVariable` has been initialized

Comment: `..Doing stuff with currentSession..` -- move that code into the `observe()` lambda expression, so it will be executed when the session becomes available.

Comment: I've thinked of that but, I'm either using it with a MapView, so that mean ReCreate the map every time the session change, or either in a `if()` statement in an `onClickListener` that I can't put in the `observe()`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is what you need, but maybe you can use a loading to show in the ui until the requirements that you need are met.

In yout view model you can have this:

```
private val _loading = MutableLiveData<Boolean>().apply(value = false)
val loading: LiveData<Boolean>
  get() = _loading
```

And then change the value of loading to true when you launch your session and to false when it finishes. You just need to observe the loading in your fragment and show it to the user.

Comment: Thanks but it's not really what I need, I don't need to wait for the UI, I need to wait these variables to use them to initialize other stuff like a GoogleMap

Answer (score 1):

It's actually rather easy:

> and I need to wait for the variables to be initialized in my ViewModel to use them in my Fragment, mainly to initialize other things like a GoogleMap but also for other purposes (like check condition for navigation, etc...). Plus, I actually need to wait for an Args from Navigation

You don't need to wait for the variables.

You expose a `LiveData<T>` instead of your variable, which lets you observe for changes.

Such change includes initialization, because the value is retrieved asynchronously.

So you need to proceed with your logic only when your LiveDatas contain the required data.

```
viewModel.session.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
    currentSession = it
    ..Doing stuff with currentSession..
})
```